# Recursive to Iterative Transformation

Tags: c++, recursion, iteration, transformation

I've gotten stuck on trying to re-write my code from a recursive function into an iterative function.

I thought I'd ask if there are any general things to think about/tricks/guidelines etc... in regards to going from recursive code to iterative code.

e.g. I can't rly get my head around how to get the following code iterative, mainly due to the loop inside the recursion which further depends on and calls the next recursion.

```
struct entry
{
    uint8_t values[8];
    int32_t num_values;
    std::array<entry, 256>* next_table;

    void push_back(uint8_t value) {values[num_values++] = value;}
};

struct node
{
    node*               children; // +0 right, +1 left
    uint8_t             value;
    uint8_t             is_leaf;
};

void build_tables(node* root, std::array<std::array<entry, 8>, 255>& tables, int& table_count)
{
    int table_index = root->value; // root is always a non-leave, thus value is the current table index.

    for(int n = 0; n < 256; ++n)
    {
        auto current = root;

        // Recurse the the huffman tree bit by bit for this table entry
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        {
            current = current->children + ((n >> i) & 1); // Travel to the next node    current->children[0] is left child and current->children[1] is right child. If current is a leaf then current->childen[0/1] point to the root.
            if(current->is_leaf)
                tables[table_index][n].push_back(current->value);
        }

        if(!current->is_leaf)
        {
            if(current->value == 0) // For non-leaves, the "value" is the sub-table index for this particular non-leave node
            {
                current->value = table_count++;
                build_tables(current, tables, table_count);
            }

            tables[table_index][n].next_table = &tables[current->value];
        }
        else
            tables[table_index][n].next_table = &tables[0];
    }   
}
```

Comment: Consider this question: (Possible duplicate?) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549943/design-patterns-for-converting-recursive-algorithms-to-iterative-ones

Comment: Great link! Thank you, didn't find it when I was searching before. I was aware of the std::stack way of doing it. However, I seem to get a bit confused by the fact that I have a loop inside my recursion that the next recursion depends on, not sure how to handle that?

Comment: It would encourage me to answer if you provided an explanation of what the code does, I don't have the time to try to figure it out myself. Edit: a loop inside a recursion would turn into a loop inside a loop.

Comment: I'm building a table for huffman decoding (google: "efficient huffman decoding"). So the "node" structure is a huffman tree, from which I wish to generate the decoding table.

Comment: It would probably help to show how the `node` struct is defined.

Comment: I've updated the code with the struct definitions.

Comment: people ask about huffman encoding a lot too, ie: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440094/what-is-the-most-efficient-of-building-a-canonical-huffman-tree

Comment: I've got the enture huffman coding functionality working. It just that this particular code is slow due to its recursion, which is why I would like to rewrite it.

Comment: It was simple to solve, dunno why I got stuck on it, please vote for close as it's a duplicate of what was mentioned in the first link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `tables` and `table_count` always refer to the same objects, you might make a small performance gain by taking `tables` and `table_count` out of the argument list of `build_tables` by storing them as members of a temporary struct and then doing something like this:

```
struct build_tables_struct
{
  build_tables_struct(std::array<std::array<entry, 8>, 255>& tables, int& table_count) :
    tables(tables), table_count(table_count) {}
  std::array<std::array<entry, 8>, 255>& tables;
  int& table_count;
  build_tables_worker(node* root) 
  {
     ...
     build_tables_worker(current); // instead of build_tables(current, tables, table_count);
     ...
  }
}

void build_tables(node* root, std::array<std::array<entry, 8>, 255>& tables, int& table_count)
{
  build_tables_struct(tables, table_count).build_tables_worker(root);
}
```

This applies of course only if your compiler is not smart enough to make this optimisation itself.

The only way you can make this non-recursive otherwise is managing the stack yourself. I doubt this would be much if any faster than the recursive version.

This all being said, I doubt your performance issue here is recursion. Pushing three reference arguments to the stack and calling a function I don't think is a huge burden compared to the work your function does.